# Android add contact email

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to insert a new contact into the Androids contact list. Adding a name and phone numbers works fine, but adding an email address doesn't work. My code:

```
//name is a string
//phone and email are string arrays
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(People.NAME, name);
Uri newPerson = People.createPersonInMyContactsGroup(cr, values);
if (newPerson != null) {
    for (i=0; i<phone.length; i++) {
        Log.i("Phone",""+phone[i]);
        values.clear();
        Uri mobilesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(newPerson,People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        values.put(People.Phones.NUMBER,phone[i]);
        values.put(People.Phones.TYPE,People.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE);
        Uri phonesUpdate = cr.insert(mobilesUri, values);
    }
    for (i=0; i<email.length; i++) {
        Log.i("Email",""+email[i]);
        values.clear();
        Uri emailUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(newPerson,People.ContactMethods.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        values.put(People.ContactMethods.KIND,People.ContactMethods.KIND_EMAIL);
        values.put(People.ContactMethods.TYPE,People.ContactMethods.TYPE_HOME);
        values.put(People.ContactMethods.DATA,email[i]);
        Uri emailUpdate = cr.insert(emailUri, values);
    }
}
```

I get an error in this line:

```
values.put(People.ContactMethods.KIND,People.ContactMethods.KIND_EMAIL);
```

of

> error: cannot find symbol

Edit: I forgot to mention I use [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode)/[Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) and revision 8 (2.2 ([Froyo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Version_history))).

Comment: At runtime or compile time? I'm guessing runtime as that looks OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    values.put(People.ContactMethods.KIND, Contacts.KIND_EMAIL);
```

which I got from the well-hidden (at least for Contact programming info):
[developer.android.com: Content Providers: Modifying data in a provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#modifying)

Answer (score 0):

You may get some help from this example: [Android Developers - ContactOperations](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/platform/ContactOperations.html).

Comment: Is there a way to insert a picture with this Intent